# How to use $this-uri-segment on the second page

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i have these pages with title using a background image. on the first page, the background would show image just fine, but the second page showing blank background.

i tried changing it to `segment(2)` with different name and different picture on the directory but it wont fix it.

this is the line i used:

```
style="background-image: url(public/frontend/home/title_bg/<?php echo $this->uri->segment(1)?>.jpg);">
```

in the first page i used `$this->uri->segment(1)` and in the directory i named the file to `product.jpg`.

can i use `segment(1)` with the same name and the same picture on the second page ? and how do i do it ?

Comment: Is `$this->uri` what you expect it to be? Shouldn't it be something like `echo $uri->segment(1);`?

Comment: @Qirel but on the first page i used $this->uri just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you properly set the uri segment. take a look at this Codeigniter Samaple.

```
http://example.com/index.php/news/local/metro/crime_is_up
The segment numbers would be this:

$this->uri->segment(1) = news
$this->uri->segment(2) = local
$this->uri->segment(3) = metro
$this->uri->segment(4) = crime_is_up
```

In your case, i believed you name your function under your controller to **product**
and you get the result. you can use `segment(1)` again if you create another Controller with the same function name. what you do is not advisable, if you want to call an image again to another function just call the name of the image so it will be like this.

```
url(public/frontend/home/title_bg/<?php echo product.jpg);
```

let me know the result.